# List of functions in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Supposedly I have those functions of the same type and result in Haskell:

```
add_one :: Integer -> Integer
add_one n = n + 1

multiply_by_five :: Integer -> Integer
multiply_by_five n = n * 5

subtract_four :: Integer -> Integer
subtract_four n = n - 4

add_ten :: Integer -> Integer
add_ten n = n + 10
```

How can I make a list from them so I can apply it to one single argument of Integer type such as:

```
map ($ single_argument) list_of_functions
```

?

Comment: What do you want as result? A list of results, or do you want to sequence the functions?

Comment: In Haskell, you make a list by listing the elements inside square brackets, like [1,2,3]

Comment: Why not use dot notation to 'string' functions together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Constructing lists with Haskel is done by using the (:) and [] list constructors, like so:

```
fList :: [Integer -> Integer]
fList = add_one : multiply_by_five : subtract_four : add_ten : []

-- or by using some syntactic sugar
fList' = [add_one, multiply_by_five, subtract_four, add_ten]
```

You can then indeed map application:

```
map ($ 3) fList
```

Comment: `map ($ 3) fs == ($ 3) <$> fs == [($ 3)] <*> fs == fs <*> [3] == sequence fs 3` as well (with `Control.Applicative`).